# ts: export default functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Just wondering if I can do this without declaring a separate `const`:

```
const MyComponent: React.SFC<props> = () => {};
export default MyComponent
```

I want something like:

```
export default (MyComponent: React.SFC<props>) = () => {};
```

but I can't figure out the syntax

Answer (score 6):

It is:

```
export default (() => {
  ...
}) as React.SFC<props>;
```